# What's the single word for "too specific"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the single word for "too specific"? For example:

> If the content of the post is deemed **too specific**, the moderators will...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kind of depends on the nature of the specificity.

For "specific" to mean, "of limited interest", you might consider *[esoteric](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/esoteric)*.

For "insufficiently broad", then you might consider *[narrow](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/narrow)* (sense 2)

Comment: Are you suggesting that *esoteric* or *narrow* can replace "too specific" or just "specific"?

Comment: I think 'esoteric' carries the implication of "too" specific... people rarely describe something as esoteric with a positive intention.

Answer (score 1):

[hyperspecific](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hyperspecific) (Wiktionary)

> *hyper-* +‎ *specific*
>   Adjective
>   **hyperspecific** (comparative **more hyperspecific**, superlative **most hyperspecific**)
>   
>    1. Very highly specific.

What more do we need!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with either idiomatic or singular.

Comment: You might consider fleshing this out with citations. A good answer here will cite an authority.